# Render a selected image from the option in Django Template

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-templates

I have been trying to figure out how to render an image in a img tag (id="show_file") when a user selected an option in Django Template.

Below is the part in question of my source code:

```
{% block content %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery.init.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var changeImage = function() {
            document.getElementById("show_file").src = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
        }

        var imageList = document.getElementById("already_exist_file");
        imageList.addEventListener("change", changeImage, True);
    </script>
.
.
.
.
<br>
                <label for="already_exist_file">기존 이미지 사용</label>
                <select id="already_exist_file" name="image_url" class="selBox">
                    <option value="없음">(없음)</option>
                    {% for notice in notice_list %}
                        <option id="image" data-style="background-image: url({{notice.image}})" value="{{notice.image}}">
                            {{notice.image}}
                        </option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <img id="show_file">
                <br>
```

And this is what the page looks like:

[image]

When the image URL is selected, the img tag still does not show the image.

Comment: Hi you might be getting error for `True` it should be `true`. Everything else seems ok in your code here is working code : https://jsfiddle.net/ymeq1vrn/